# Why arraylist can't add string?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

In my code i made

```
ArrayList<String> allpromo =new ArrayList<>();
```

as global variable and in onCreate(){}

i wrote

```
database.getReference().child("PromoCodes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                allpromo.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String val=snapshot1.child("Promo").getValue(String.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    allpromo.add(val);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


if(allpromo.isEmpty()) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

It is displaying me all contents of "Promo" from firebase but why it is not able to add items in arraylist.
Beacause it Toast "0" .It means mine arraylist is remain empty.And still it Toast items of firebase

But why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIXc0.png)

and my database is

Comment: What is getting toasted first? "0" or the values?

Comment: Loading data from Firebase requires it to make a call over the internet. Like many cloud-based APIs/SDKs, Firebase implements this as an asynchronous operation so that your user can continue to use the app while the data is being retrieved. Then when the data is available, your `onDataChange` is called with that data. But by that time, your toast has long since shown the empty `allpromo`. The solution for this is always the same: all code that needs the data from the database, has to be inside `onDataChange`, be called from there, or otherwise synchronized.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen tx Frank van puffelen..Tx alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
database.getReference().child("PromoCodes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                allpromo.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String val=snapshot1.child("Promo").getValue(String.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    allpromo.add(val);
                }
         if(allpromo.isEmpty()) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "0", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: still not adding

Comment: show me the value of snapshot1.child("Promo") in firebase

Comment: adnan i marked that if add individually any value let suppose "1" like allpromo.add("1"); in  that for loop than still it shows that arraylist is empty,But if i add any value outstide addValueEventListner{..} then it work perfectly

Comment: But i dont why it is happening

Comment: adnan i edited see please

Comment: their is two possible reasons for this ,
1- you toast it from success listener 
2-your child name is invalid 

OS can't wait for awaiting tasks that's why it execute your toast line before the executing success listener because successlistener is Awaiting method

Comment: i edit  please replace  this

Comment: Tx adnan got it